# how to pass the value for fun2 which is in fun1

Tags: r, datatable

I tried to show the two columns into separate like in the image but i am getting an error In rbind(df, subrow) : number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

```
expand_collapse <- function(right_table){
  
  sector_list <- unique(right_table$Sector)
  df = data.frame("Sector1"=c(""),"Sector"=c(""),"Incubatee"=c(""),"Actual"=c(""))
  
  my_fun <- function(s){
    df1 = right_table[right_table$Sector==s,]
    sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
    Sector = df1$Sector[1]
    Incubatee = ""
    actual = as.character(nrow(df1))
    mainrow = c(sector1,Sector,Incubatee,actual) 
    df = rbind(df,mainrow)
    incubatee_list <<- unique(df1$Incubatee)
  }
  df = do.call(rbind,lapply(sector_list, my_fun))
  
  my_fun2 <- function(i){
    df2 = right_table[right_table$Incubatee==i,]
    sector1 = df1$Sector[1]
    Sector = ""
    Incubatee = df2$Incubatee[1]
    actual = nrow(df2)
    subrow = c(sector1,Sector,Incubatee,actual)
    df = rbind(df,subrow)
  }
  df = do.call(cbind,lapply(incubatee_list, my_fun2))
  df = df[2:nrow(df),]
  df$Actual = as.numeric(df$Actual)
  df_total = nrow(right_table)
  df = rbind(df,c("","Total","",df_total))
  return(df)
}
```

DT::datatable(expand_collapse(x), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=0),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))),class='hover cell-border stripe')

Answer (score 0):

I tried going through your function but it was difficult to understand what exactly you were trying to do. Here are some inconsistencies and problems I found with the code:

- You define `sector_list` at the beginning, but define `incubatee_list` using `<<-` in `my_fun()` and it's unclear why.
- `my_fun()` and `my_fun2()` don't seem to actually return anything, and I wasn't sure if you meant to use `<<-` on the `df` variable in each of these functions.
- `my_fun2()` refers to `df1` which causes an error.

You likely don't need to adopt such a complicated method for producing the table in the screenshot. Here is an example of what you could do instead.

```
# First I'm going to add one more row to the data so that I could demonstrate 
# more clearly what will happen if there is more than one Incubatee per sector. 
# I create "Test" under the sector "Energy and CleanTech" with a count of 5.
library(tidyverse)
x = x %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(
    Incubatee = "Test", 
    Sector = "Energy & CleanTech",
    count = 5,
    type = "Actual",
    qtr = "Q2",
    year = 2021
  ))

# A tibble: 3 x 12
  Incubatee     Sector   date        year month qtr   year_range count type  yrmo 
  <chr>         <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <fct> <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <fct>
1 "SpotSense"   Health   2021-07-01  2021 Jul   Q2    2021-2022      1 Actu~ Jul-~
2 "Devidayal S~ Energy ~ 2021-08-01  2021 Aug   Q2    2021-2022      1 Actu~ Aug-~
3 "Test"        Energy ~ NA          2021 NA    Q2    NA             5 Actu~ NA   
# ... with 2 more variables: qtr_yr <fct>, m_date <chr>
```

Here is a suggested pipeline using the tidyverse.

```
expand_collapse = function(data) {
  data %>% 
    split(.$Sector) %>% 
    map_df(function(sector_data) {
      main_row = tibble(
        Sector = sector_data$Sector[1],
        Incubatee = "",
        Actual = sum(sector_data$count)
      ) 
    
      incubatee_rows = sector_data %>% 
        group_by(Incubatee) %>% 
        summarise(
          Sector = "",
          Actual = sum(count)
        )
      
      bind_rows(main_row, incubatee_rows)
    }) %>% 
    # Create a total row
    bind_rows(tibble(
      Sector = "Total",
      Incubatee = "",
      Actual = sum(data$count)
    ))
}
```

To demonstrate the output:

```
> expand_collapse(x)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Sector               Incubatee                    Actual
  <chr>                <chr>                         <dbl>
1 "Energy & CleanTech" ""                                6
2 ""                   "Devidayal Solar Solutions "      1
3 ""                   "Test"                            5
4 "Health"             ""                                1
5 ""                   "SpotSense"                       1
6 "Total"              ""                                7
```

**Edit:** base R solution, and note that I define `Actual` by the number of rows instead of using `sum(count)`.

```
create_sector_section = function(sector_data) {
  main_row = data.frame(
    Sector = sector_data$Sector[1],
    Incubatee = "",
    Actual = nrow(sector_data),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ) 
  
  incubatee_rows = lapply(
    unique(sector_data$Incubatee),
    function(inc) {
      data.frame(
        Sector = "",
        Incubatee = inc,
        Actual = sum(sector_data$Incubatee == inc),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    }
  )
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(list(main_row), incubatee_rows))
}

expand_collapse = function(data) {
  sector_data = split(data, data$Sector)
  sector_sections = lapply(sector_data, create_sector_section)
  total_row = data.frame(
    Sector = "Total",
    Incubatee = "",
    Actual = nrow(data),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(sector_sections, list(total_row)))
}
```

Output

```
> expand_collapse(x)
              Sector                  Incubatee Actual
1 Energy & CleanTech                                 2
2                    Devidayal Solar Solutions       1
3                                          Test      1
4             Health                                 1
5                                     SpotSense      1
6              Total                                 3
```

The main improvements this solution has over your original implementation:

- Use `split()` to obtain a list of data frames for each different Sector.
- Use data frames to create the smaller parts of your desired output.
- Use `Reduce()` to put everything back together.

Comment: I modified the sample code @kybazzi actually i just need to convert the for loop into apply

Comment: In the version I posted, I use `purrr::map_df()` which is similar. Did you want your solution to be in base R?

Comment: base r means it would be more readable or i dont know which is good for code optimazation @kybazzi

Comment: It depends on your requirements and preferences - both solutions are perfectly fine from an optimization standpoint. In terms of readability, it is subjective but I'd consider my implementation to be more straightforward. If you have any specific concerns with the solution given let me know and I will try to address it.

Comment: Also, note that I deviate from the logic you used in the question, defining `Actual` to be the sum of `count` instead of just the number of rows. These are things you may need to change if my understanding of the data was incorrect.

Comment: if it solved using  any apply family it will be more useful because like this i have many function in that there are so many nested for loops . if it is done using apply i will easily replicate to other functions @kybazzi

Comment: I update the actual function kindly check the function to get more clarity about the data and the requirement @kybazzi

Comment: @MyneedPersonal I've updated the code with a base R solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499060/how-to-enhance-the-r-code-for-better-preformance <- i have a similar questions with multiple columns to show the total of the rows kindly check and share your suggestion @kybazzi